# Meaning of nested if using python

Tags: python, if-statement

Does anyone know why code doesn't work when the number I put for b is bigger than a. I am learning about nested if with python:

```
a=int(input('What is the first number?'))
b=int(input('What is the second number?'))

if a>b:
    print('a is bigger than b')
    if b>a:
        print('b is bigger than a')
```

Comment: There is no nested `if` there. There are two separate `if` statements, and at most *one* of the two conditions can be true. For example, if `a > b` is true, then `b > a` is necessarily false. (It's possible neither is true, as `a` and `b` could be equal.)

Comment: What about this do you think does not work?

Comment: can you explain what is not working?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.

Comment: But if I run it as two seperate if statements it works:
```
a=500
b=4000

if a>b:
    print('a is bigger than b')
if b>a:
    print('b is bigger than a')
```

Comment: I fixed it I was eidtting it and didn't want to post it yet, you guys are so fast

Comment: It works with two seperate if statement but not nested that's my question

Comment: it's simple logic 500 never greater than 4000 it fails so it will never check `b>a`

Comment: Lets say I am getting two numers from the user

Comment: Add your examples and explanation in the post not in comments

Comment: Ok  I fixed the question now it is ready

Comment: @Barmar fixed it, still doesn't work

Comment: What is the result you expect? If `a` is bigger than `b`, it can't also be the case that `b` is bigger than `a`.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: There should be something about nested if definition that makes it behave this way, that is what I am looking for

Comment: Well if the input number for b is bigger than a it doesn't print anything

Comment: Only print the message when a is bigger than b

Comment: I wonder why it only works for a>b and not the otherway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `b` is bigger than `a`, the first `if` condition fails. That means that nothing inside that `if` block is executed. This includes the nested `if` statement. So it never performs the test for `b > a`, and then it never prints `b is bigger than a`.

When you have mutually exclusive conditions, you shouldn't use nested `if`, you should use `elif`.

```
if a > b:
    print('a is bigger than b')
elif b > a:
    print('b is bigger than a')
else:
    print('a and b are the same')
```

Nested `if` is useful when you want to test additional conditions, not alternatives.

```
a=int(input('What is the first number?'))
b=int(input('What is the second number?'))
c=int(input('What is the third number?'))

if a < b:
    if (b < c):
        print('The numbers are in order')
    elif (c < b):
        print('The first two numbers are in order, but not the third')
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two different inputs- [a](/questions/tagged/a) and [b](/questions/tagged/b). If [a](/questions/tagged/a) is already greater than [b](/questions/tagged/b), then [b](/questions/tagged/b) cannot be greater than [a](/questions/tagged/a). But, [b](/questions/tagged/b) can be equal  to [a](/questions/tagged/a). So, your code first checks whether [a](/questions/tagged/a) is greater than [b](/questions/tagged/b) or not, and if your input for [a](/questions/tagged/a) is greater than [b](/questions/tagged/b) then it again checks if [b](/questions/tagged/b) is greater than [a](/questions/tagged/a) or not, which does not make sense. You have used nested if-statement, which is if-statement inside if-statement. As the condition for [b](/questions/tagged/b) is inside `if a>b:` , your code does not examine [b](/questions/tagged/b).

```
if a>b:
    print(arguments)
elif a == b:
    print(arguments)
else:   #this is if b>a
    print(arguments)
```